# How to transform a key, value table into a list lua

Tags: lua, transform

Having a table in lua like:
`tab = {a="hello", b="world"}`

how to flatten it into a list of key, values:
`{"a", "hello", "b", "world"}`

I managed to write some code that seems to work :

```
function expand(t)
  local i = 1
  local res = {}
  for k, v in pairs(t) do
    res[i] = k
    i = i + 1
    res[i] = v
    i = i + 1
  end
  return res
end
```

I wonder if there is a more compact way of doing it in lua:

Comment: The task is not well posed because the pairs in a Lua table are unordered. If you can accept any order, then your solution is fine.

Comment: @lhf There are valid use cases because we don't always care about order. For example, to store a hash-like Lua table into a redis ```HASH``` we can use ```redis.call('hset', 'foo', unpack(expand(tab))```

Comment: @clpgr, fair enough. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @lhf, thanks for the example as it that is exactly my use case: in a redis lua script one of the arguments is a msgpacked buffer which I wanted to store as a redis hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is eliminating the unnecessary `i`.

```lua
function expand(t)
    local res = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        res[#res + 1] = k
        res[#res + 1] = v
    end
    return res
end
```

Besides that, I don't know any other possible optimizations (in the sense of compactness).

---

I wrote a simple test and found that the time penalty of this code over the OP's code grows with the number of keys of the table. For some reason, it grows faster with luajit than with lua5.3.

```lua
local function benchmark(funcs, t, times)
    times = times or 1000000
    local s, e

    local diffs = {}
    for name, f in pairs(funcs) do
        s = os.clock()
        for i = 1, times do
            f(t)
        end
        e = os.clock()
        diffs[name] = e - s
    end
    return diffs
end

-- base, length and insert are functions correspond to the OP's version,
-- the version in this answer and the version with table.insert respectively.
local funcs = { base = base, length = length, insert = insert }

io.write('nkeys\tbase\tlength\tinsert\n')
for _, nkeys in ipairs{4, 8, 16, 32, 64} do
    -- get_tab(n) returns a table with n keys. Its definition is omitted.
    local res = benchmark(funcs, get_tab(nkeys))
    io.write(string.format("%d\t1.0\t%.2f\t%.2f\n",
                           nkeys, res.length/res.base, res.insert/res.base))
end
```

output:

```
$ luajit ./flatten.lua
nkeys   base    length  insert
4       1.0     1.15    1.55
8       1.0     1.33    1.89
16      1.0     1.55    2.47
32      1.0     1.72    2.82
64      1.0     2.00    3.72

$ lua5.3 ./flatten.lua
nkeys   base    length  insert
4       1.0     1.13    1.56
8       1.0     1.24    1.78
16      1.0     1.28    1.95
32      1.0     1.36    2.12
64      1.0     1.56    2.34
```

We can also see that `table.insert()` is even slower than `res[#res + 1] =`.

Comment: I doubt this is faster than the OP's code because `#` is not an O(1) operation. Your code was twice as slow in a simple benchmark I wrote.

Comment: @lhf optimization in the sense of compactness (what OP asked for) not in the sense of efficiency. Does changing it to ```table.insert()``` improve the performance?